# Android code overwritten by gibberish characters

Tags: android, eclipse, data-recovery

[image]

Hi all. Today when I opened my eclipse some of the files in my particular project were seen as below. I havent really experienced such a problem and i dont know how to recover my overwritten code. I have tried cleaning up the project and restarting eclipse but nothing seems to work. any help is welcome. As it is very important for me to recover these files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click on the file and go to Local History, if there is any version there, recover it.

Comment: ...and then check for viruses...

Comment: and always use version control system, even at home

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I could recover all the files. Thank you. I was wondering what is the reason for this happening. what were those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch the local history of the file in Eclipse. If something exists there, restore it.
Right click on project:

[image]